# How to use the same time indices with different meaning

Tags: pyomo

I am new in pyomo. I am trying to code three decision variables with indices t. For example y_j^t and X_ij^t and u_i^t. However, every t in these variables are belong to different categories. How can I code it? As you see, they all have t . But for example t in y means time of departure and in x means time of loading. Should i define three different sets for t?

Comment: "However,...these variables are belong to different catagories. ...........Should i define three different sets for t?"   Why should you not do that? When they are different, then you should treat them as different.

Comment: The typical way to handle this would be to use subsets.  So, if you have one set, `T` with all the viable times in it, then just create as many subsets as you need to satisfy your formulation... `model.T_departures = pyo.Set(within=model.T, ...)`, `model.T_arrivals=...`